# Using regex to get information inside an HTML tag

Tags: java, regex

I'm wondering how I could extract '4151' from the following code:

`</th><td><a class="external exitstitial" rel="nofollow" href="http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/viewitem.ws?obj=4151">Look up price</a>`

I would like to use regex but if there is a better way I'm open for it!

Comment: Assuming that's just a fragment of a complete (X)HTML document, use XPath first to obtain the attribute value, _then_ a regular expression to extract the query parameter.

Comment: I've already done all of that, I just need the regex to extract it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me, assuming the `href` attribute value was already extracted:

```
String href = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/viewitem.ws?obj=4151";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\?obj=(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(href);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Outputs "4151"

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few parser libraries : [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), [jsoup](http://jsoup.org), and [jtidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

In your case, regex may be fine, but here's a classic post of why [you should avoid regex for html parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

This regex would get you the number -

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

This code is not tested and presumes your HTML string is assigned to the 'subjectString' variable.